# file_get_contents failed to open stream HTTP request failed?

Tags: php

In an ubuntu server, this error :

```
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https://127.0.0.1/graphs/makeReportPDF.php?debut=2021-03-29&fin=2021-03-31&repid=9): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
```

The executed code :

```
$opts=array(
        "ssl"=>array(
                "verify_peer"=>false,
                "verify_peer_name"=>false,
 ),
);

$result = file_get_contents('https://127.0.0.1/graphs/makeReportPDF.php?debut=2021-03-29&fin=2021-03-31&repid=9', false, stream_context_create($opts));
echo $result;
```

It worked until now.
If I type the link in the browser, it works correctly.

Do you have an idea?

Thanks

Comment: Check the server log to see what error is happening in he `makeReportPDF.php` script.

Comment: I can't find any errors in the logs.
If I run this address in the browser, it works

Comment: `127.0.0.1` is localhost. So if you run it in the browser, it uses the same machine as the browser. If you run it in the PHP script, it uses the PHP server. So they're only equivalent if you're running the PHP script on the local machine.

Comment: I run it with the WAN IP on another browser.